# How do you make iSync (on Snow Leopard) sync automatically?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

Is there an easy way to get the iSync software on Snow Leopard (verson 3.1.0) auto sync every x minutes?

I've set it up to sync with Google contacts (in Gmail), but I'd like it to run automatically in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an Apple script to automatically tell iSync to sync.

```
tell application "iSync"

    if not syncing then
        synchronize
        repeat while syncing
            delay 1
        end repeat
        quit
    end if

end tell
```

Set it to run at period intervals using Automator workflows.

Comment: That opens iSync, is there a way to do it in the background?